# SQLite AUTO_INCREMENT id field not working

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, cs50

I am trying to create a database using python to execute the SQL commands (for CS50x problem set 7).

I have created a table with an **`id` field set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`**, but the field in the database is **populated only by `NULL` values**. I just want it to have an incrementing id starting at 1.

I've tried searching online to see if I'm using the right syntax and can't find anything obvious, nor can I find someone else with a similar problem, so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the SQL command I am running:

```
# For creating the table
db.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE students (
                id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                middle_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT (NULL),
                last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                house VARCHAR(10),
                birth INTEGER
            );
       """)

# An example insert statement
db.execute("""
            INSERT INTO students (
                first_name,
                middle_name,
                last_name,
                house,
                birth
            )
            VALUES (
                ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
            );
    """, "Harry", "James", "Potter", "Gryffindor", 1980)
```

Here is a screenshot of the database schema shown in `phpliteadmin` :

[image: Database schema shown in phpliteadmin]

And here is a screenshot of the resulting database:

[image: Resulting database shown in phpliteadmin]

Comment: I think you need to add `NOT NULL` for that `id` column.

Comment: @Akina if the table already existed then the app would crash and no rows would be inserted. The issue here is that the OP is not using MySql but SQLite.

Comment: @Akina sorry there's a line I haven't included at the start of the program where I clear the .db file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are using SQLite with phpliteadmin and not MySql, in which case this:

```
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

is not the correct definition of the [auto increment primary key](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

In fact, the data type of this column is set to `INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT`, as you can see in `phpliteadmin`, which according to [3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity), has `INTEGER` affinity.
Nevertheless it is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table but this allows `NULL` values.

The correct syntax to have an integer primary key is this:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot happen, if your statements are executed correctly.

I notice that you are not checking for errors in your code.  You should be doing that!

My guess is that the table is *already* created without the `auto_increment` attribute.  The `create table` is generating an error and you are inserting into the older version.

You can fix this by dropping the table before you create it.  You should also modify the code to check for errors.

Comment: The table doesn't exist before I create it, there's a line earlier in the file where I empty the existing .db file, and I've checked that works. I have also tried dropping the students table in phpliteadmin and re-running my script and it still doesn't update the id variable.

Comment: But thank you for your answer, how can I check for error messages from the SQL statements?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax of SQLite **CREATE** statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    id INTEGER,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    middle_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT (NULL),
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    house VARCHAR(10),
    birth INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id AUTOINCREMENT)
)
```